# Hide and show chart container in lightningchart js

Tags: lightningchart

how do I toggle the chart visibility ,

in version 3.4 I just used jquery to $("#container").toggle(); , it used to hide/show the container...

But now When I do the same in version 4.0.0 I get following error.

```
Uncaught Error: EngineError: Could not create vertex buffer
```

Comment: This is most likely a bug introduced in v4.0.0. We'll patch it either today or early next week.

Comment: there is 4.0.1 in npmjs , shall I try it ?

Comment: New patch will be coming for this.

Comment: Hi , when can i expect the patch.

Comment: v4.0.2 is live in NPM. It should patch this issue, please update here if it does / doesn't do so.

Comment: thanks , looks like this bug is fixed

Comment: Hi , sometimes I get this error - Uncaught Error: EngineError: Could not create vertex buffer –